# Optimum performance of GPU

Tags: performance, cuda

I have been asked to measure how "efficiently " does my code use the GPU /what % of peak performance are algorithms achieving.I am not sure how to do this comparison.Till now I have basically had timers put in my code and measure the execution.How can I compare this to optimal performance and  find what might be the bottle necks? (I did hear about visual profiler but couldnt get it to work ..it keeps giving me "cannot load output" error).

Comment: It will be worthwhile to get the profiler to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each card has a maximum memory bandwidth and processing speed. For example, the GTX 480 bandwidth is 177.4 GB/s. You will need to know the specs for your card.

The first thing to decide is whether your code is memory bound or computation bound. If it is clearly one or the other, that will help you focus on the correct "efficiency" to measure. If your program is memory bound, then you need to compare your bandwidth with the cards maximum bandwidth.

You can calculate memory bandwidth by computing the amount of memory you read/write and dividing by run time (I use cuda events for timing). Here is a good example of [calculating bandwidth efficiency](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/Data-Parallel_Algorithms.html#reduction) (look at the whitepaper for the parallel reduction) and using it to help validate a kernel.

---

1. *I don't know very much about determining the efficiency if instead you are ALU bound. You can probably count (or profile) the number of instructions, but what is the card's maximum?*
2. *I'm also not sure what to do in the likely case that your kernel is something in between memory bound and ALU bound.*

Anyone...?

Comment: Thanks jmilloy .My implementation is clearly IO bound and so I guess major chunk of it is taken by memory transfer.So I shall apply the frst technique of calculating bw efficiency.

Comment: what about in the case "computation bound"?

Answer (score 0):

Generally "efficiently" would probably be a measure of how much memory and GPU cycles (average, min, max) of your program is using.  Then the efficiency measure would be avg(mem)/total memory for the time period and so on with AVG(GPU cycles)/Max GPU cycles.

Then I'd compare these metrics to metrics from some GPU benchmark suites (which you can assume to be pretty efficient at using most of the GPU).  Or you could measure against some random GPU intensive programs of your choice.  That'd be how I'd do it but I've never thought to try so good luck!

As for bottlenecks and "optimal" performance.  These are probably NP-Complete problems that no one can help you with.  Get out the old profiler and debuggers and start working your way through your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to go about the first part? (finding max /avg GPU cycles)?If that helps For timing purposes I right now use cutStartTimer and cutStopTimer.Also could there be a possible use of bandwidthtest.cu program that comes with the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with profiler and microoptimisation, but there is a CUDA calculator http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls , which trys to estimate how does your CUDA code use the hardware resources, based on this values:

```
Threads Per Block
Registers Per Thread                                                             
Shared Memory Per Block (bytes)
```

Comment: .I read the documentation that came with the calculator .However I am not sure how to find out the shared memory per block/registers per thread value.I use visual studio.I did something like-> nvcc- ..(options)..filename from windows command prompt but it didnt work.Could you tell me how can I find these parameters? ?

Comment: The occupancy calculator simply tries to help you determine the best configuration for your kernel, and to help you identify if you are using the device resources inefficiently. It does NOT tell you your bandwidth or computation efficiency.